# Creating a Hello World application using AWS SAM : issue when running "sam build"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dependencies, sam

I am just getting started with AWS SAM. I tried following Amazon's tutorial : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html.
But I am stuck at Step #2 : When I run "sam build" in the directory of the application, i get this error :

```
C:\Users\emman\HelloWorldAPI>sam build
Building resource 'HelloWorldFunction'
Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - Could not satisfy the requirement: requests
```

I am using Python 3.7.7 on anaconda. How can I fix this dependency problem ?

Here is the full debug :

```
sam build --debug
Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
'build' command is called
No Parameters detected in the template
2 resources found in the template
Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and CodeUri='hello_world/'
Building resource 'HelloWorldFunction'
Loading workflow module 'aws_lambda_builders.workflows'
Registering workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'NodejsNpmBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='nodejs', dependency_manager='npm', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'GoDepBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='dep', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'GoModulesBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='modules', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'JavaMavenWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='maven', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
Found workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
Running workflow 'PythonPipBuilder'
Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
calling pip download -r C:\Users\emman\HelloWorldAPI\hello_world\requirements.txt --dest C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdzzen475
PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\actions.py", line 42, in execute
    requirements_path=self.manifest_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 137, in build_dependencies 
    self._dependency_builder.build_site_packages(requirements_path, artifacts_dir_path, scratch_dir_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 198, in build_site_packages
    wheels, packages_without_wheels = self._download_dependencies(scratch_directory, requirements_filepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 222, in _download_dependencies
    deps = self._download_all_dependencies(requirements_filename, directory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 305, in _download_all_dependencies
    self._pip.download_all_dependencies(requirements_filename, directory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 594, in download_all_dependencies
    raise NoSuchPackageError(str(package_name))
aws_lambda_builders.workflows.python_pip.packager.NoSuchPackageError: Could not satisfy the requirement: requests

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 269, in run
    action.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\actions.py", line 45, in execute
    raise ActionFailedError(str(ex))
aws_lambda_builders.actions.ActionFailedError: Could not satisfy the requirement: requests

Build Failed
Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'duration': 12362, 'exitReason': 'BuildError', 'exitCode': 1, 'requestId': '3281a750-00b0-409a-9248-d50da2c6873a', 'installationId': 'cd8fef36-a3f5-4145-9f80-47b50c4113c7', 'sessionId': '224c2d07-0766-4233-96a1-4433dc488353', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'pyversion': '3.7.6', 'samcliVersion': '0.47.0'}}]}
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - Could not satisfy the requirement: requests
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking at the requirements.txt file. The only line was "requests". I tried deleting it, and running "sam build" again. The build succeeded, but I am not quite sure it is that easy... 
Here is what the "sam build" returns :

```
Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam\build
Built Template   : .aws-sam\build\template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided
```

Comment: i tried and it also solve my issue. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I found another post saying I should run :

````
pip install wheel```

I did that in the anaconda prompt, but the module is already installed. 
I wonder if there is a conflict between two different pip applications...

Anaconda runs python 3.7.7 and the telemetry of "sam build --debug" returns :
```'pyversion': '3.7.6'```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by uninstalling anaconda, and by downloading the stock version of Python instead.

I'm still curious to know if Anaconda could work however.